# How can I ignore non-matching preceding text when using Scala's parser combinators?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I really like parser combinators but I'm not happy with the solution I've come up with to extract data when I don't care about the text before the relevant text.

Consider this small parser to get monetary amounts:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

case class Amount(number: Double, currency: String)

object MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def number = floatingPointNumber ^^ (_.toDouble)
  def currency = """\w+""".r ^? ({
    case "USD" => "USD"
    case "EUR" => "EUR"
  }, "Unknown currency code: " + _)

  def amount = (number ~ currency) ^^ {
    case num ~ curr => Amount(num, curr)
  } | currency ~ number ^^ {
    case curr ~ num => Amount(num, curr)
  }

  def junk = """\S+""".r
  def amountNested: Parser[Any] = amount | junk ~> amountNested
}
```

As you can see, I can get `Amount`s back easily if I give the parser a string that begins with valid data:

```
scala> MyParser.parse(MyParser.amount, "101.41 EUR")
res7: MyParser.ParseResult[Amount] = [1.11] parsed: Amount(101.41,EUR)

scala> MyParser.parse(MyParser.amount, "EUR 102.13")
res8: MyParser.ParseResult[Amount] = [1.11] parsed: Amount(102.13,EUR)
```

However, it fails when there is non-matching text before it:

```
scala> MyParser.parse(MyParser.amount, "I have 101.41 EUR")
res9: MyParser.ParseResult[Amount] = 
[1.2] failure: Unknown currency code: I

I have 101.41 EUR
 ^
```

My solution is the `amountNested` parser, in which it recursively tries to find an `Amount`. This works but it gives a `ParseResult[Any]`:

```
scala> MyParser.parse(MyParser.amountNested, "I have 101.41 EUR")
res10: MyParser.ParseResult[Any] = [1.18] parsed: Amount(101.41,EUR)
```

This loss of type information (which can be 'retrieved' using pattern matching, of course) seems unfortunately because any success will contain an `Amount`.

Is there a way to keep searching my input (`"I have 101.41 EUR"`) until I have a match or not but without having a `Parser[Any]`?

Looking at the [ScalaDocs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers%24Parser.html) it seems like the `*` method on `Parser` might help but all I get are failures or infinite loops when I try things like:

```
def amount2 = ("""\S+""".r *) ~> amount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It typechecks all right if you declare your amountNested to be Parser[Amount] :

```
def amountNested: Parser[Amount] = amount | junk ~> amountNested
```

Comment: This might result in stack overflow, however.

Comment: Wow, works for me. @DanielC.Sobral, when might it result in a stack overflow?

Comment: @didierd Err, true. I didn't notice it was part of the question itself.

Comment: @pr1001 Each "junk" character will add one stack frame, because of the non-tail recursion (the last method is `|`, and, before that, `~>`). If you use `PackratParsers`, however, you can turn that `def` into a `lazy val` and avoid the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks Daniel. Guess now I need to look into PackratParsers and whether they make sense in my case. Is it the standard rule to use them or are there significant trade-offs?